# Javascript - every() method to check isInteger on array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check return true if an array contains all integers or false if not. I am trying to use the every method [MDN docs every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every?v=example).

So if given '1234' it will return true and if given '123a' it would return false.

```
  function validatePIN (pin) {
    pinArray = pin.split("");
      if (pinArray.length === 4 || pinArray.length === 6) {
        if (pinArray.every(Number.isInteger()) === true;) {
          return true
    }};
```

How does every pass the element to isInteger so it can test it?

Comment: It doesn't. You need to *pass* `Number.isInteger` as callback, ***not call it***. `every(Number.isInteger)`…

Comment: Change it to `pinArray.every(Number.isInteger)` cause if you add the `()` you are calling the function and not giving it as a parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you fix syntax error and pass `Number.isInteger` as a function this won't work.

```js
function wrongValidatePIN (pin) {
    var pinArray = pin.split(""); // <-- array of strings
      if (pinArray.length === 4 || pinArray.length === 6) {
        if (pinArray.every(Number.isInteger)) { // <-- isInteger works with numbers
          return true
    }}
    return false
}

console.log(wrongValidatePIN('1234'))
```

You need something like this

```js
    function validatePIN (pin) {
        var pinArray = pin.split(""); // <-- array of strings
        
        return (pinArray.length === 4 || pinArray.length === 6)
           && pinArray.every(char => !Number.isNaN(Number.parseInt(char, 10)))
    }

    console.log(validatePIN('1234'), validatePIN('123a'))
```

Or you could use regexp

```js
function validatePin(pin) {
  return /^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/.test(pin)
}

console.log(validatePin('1234'), validatePin('123456'),
 validatePin('12345'), validatePin('123a'))
```

Answer (score 3):

As the comments stated, the isInteger function can be passed as an argument by calling `pinArray.every(Number.isInteger)` instead of calling it a single time, (or by providing it inside a function `.every(c=>Number.isInteger(c))` , but passing the function itself is more concise)

However, it's unlikely to provide the result you expect, because `isInteger` checks if the value is an actual integer, not if the value can be parsed to one.

That *could* be resolved with something like `pinArray.map(parseFloat).every(Number.isInteger);`

but then it would be easier to use `!pinArray.some(isNaN)`

That could make the function:

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
    return (pin.length === 4 || pin.length === 6) 
        && ![...pin].some(isNaN);
}
```

But as a final note, regular expressions are made for this type of check and could be preferable here

Answer (score 2):

Your `pin.split("")` will never work when you pass number eg. `1234` as argument. Convert to string first then split `pin.toString().split("")`.

Now inside `.every()` function we cast our string to number by doing `+number`.

```
return pinArray.every(number => Number.isInteger(+number));
```

`.every()` returns true or false.

Here is working example.

```js
function validatePIN(pin) {
      var pinArray = pin.toString().split("");
      if (pinArray.length === 4 || pinArray.length === 6) {
        // returns true or false
        // +number casts string into number
        return pinArray.every(number => Number.isInteger(+number));
      }
      // We assume that every PIN is not valid
      return false;
};
    
    
    console.log('test1', validatePIN(1234)); // true
    console.log('test2', validatePIN('1234')); // true
    console.log('test3', validatePIN('123a')); // false
    console.log('test4', validatePIN('0001')); // true
```

Comment: why is there a + infront of number? (+number)

Comment: It casts string into an number. Because your array is full of string elements. Take into consideration for example: `Number.isInteger('1');  // return false` but `Number.isInteger(+'1');  // return true`

Comment: It is called `unary operator` + `+num`.